# Android layout XML: reference system attribute value

Tags: android, android-layout

In the following XML, can I reference the width/height of `android:attr/progressBarStyle` for `android:layout_height`?

I am showing/hiding a loading circle with a text message. Since ContentLoadingProgress bar does not seem to support adding a text message, I used a TextView along with it.

I used `wrap_content` for the height/width, but the problem is when calling `show()` when it has been hidden using `hide()`, there is a split-second delay when the circle is empty and the width is collapsed. Then the circle appears, and its width is widen, and the text message moves. This looks ugly.

I want to change

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to something like

```
android:layout_width="(reference the width of android:attr/progressBarStyle)"
```

so that it would remain constant.

Layout.xml

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v4.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            />
        <TextView
            tools:text="Loading..."
            android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```